# How do I implement a special event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, image-caching

I'm using this [`plugin`](http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/blob/master/ahpi.imgload.js) to replace jQuery's `imgload` event with one that will fire regardless of whether the image is cached.

The (minimal) documentation says to use it thus:

> ```
> Usage:
> $(images).bind('load', function (e) {
> // Do stuff on load
> });
> ```

So, two questions. One, do I just link to the plugin into my header next to jQuery? And two, is my implementation

> ```
> $('#preload img:first-child').load(activateThumb);
> ```

Equivalent to the one above (ie do I need to pass `e` to the `load()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do I just link to the plugin into my header next to jQuery?` - Yes

`Equivalent to the one above (ie do I need to pass e to the load() function?` - it's up to you - if you don't need it in your handler - no need to pass `e` into it, but I think you should still use `bind` function, since I don't see that plugin adding `load` method to add event handler